# Trigger click event when you start typing in the last element in a form field (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

I'm using [this](http://vipullimbachiya.com/jQuery/Plugins/MultiField/2/index.htm) jQuery plugin which add form fields each time you click the '**add more**' like:

This is how the form looks like:

[image]

The **Menu Item** field:

```
<input tabindex="1" recname="itemName" type="text" id="itemName" name="itemName" placeholder="Menu Item" class="menu-item itemName">
```

The **Price** field:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="8" recname="itemGaylords" id="itemGaylords" name="itemGaylords" placeholder="Price" class="price numeric unitValue required">
```

The **Add more** link:

```
<a href="#" class="addMoreFields">Add more</a>
```

I would like to trigger a click in the `.addMoreFields` link as soon as you start typing in the last **Menu Item** field.

Any suggestions to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.menuItem:last').focus(function(){
  $('.addMoreFields:last').trigger('click');
});
```

Better to use ....

```
$('.menuItem:last').live('focus', function(){
  $('.addMoreFields:last').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Strange but when you place the cursor in the last (newly created field) nothing happens. The first field still is interpreted as the last one (maybe I need the to do something with the `bind` or `live` function?

Comment: I got it: `$('.menu-item:last').live('focus', function() {
     $('.addMoreFields:last').trigger('click');
 });`